# Making one variable's instance type same as that of another, programming against interfaces

Tags: java, reflection

I was writing some code that deals with HTTP response headers (an immutable collection once filled), and found myself with code like the following:

```
private Map<String,String> headers;

public ctor() {
    this.headers = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    // ... some more ... (actually, this fills this.headers based on ctor parameters)
}

public Map<String,String> getResponseHeaders() {
    Map<String,String> temp = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    temp.putAll(this.headers);
    return temp;
}
```

Looking at this, it occured to me that while I know the type of `headers` *now*, and admittedly the class in question is short enough (about 50 lines total currently, and not poised to grow much more) that in this particular case it's not a major problem, if the problem space was a bit more complex, then in `getResponseHeaders()` I might not know the type that `this.headers` (to use the names from this particular example) was instantiated to. Also, in a large class where I want to return copies of collections, keeping track of a number of different instance member variables and their types (possibly decided on by a number of factors; list size comes to mind as one *possible* consideration) could get quite hairy.

Two related questions:

Without a full-blown dependency injection framework, and barring all-out use of reflection (because of the performance penalty), is there any way to make the instance type of `temp` the same as the instance type of `this.headers` in code like the above, for the general case?

Is there any situation in which that might [realistically](http://xkcd.com/974) make much of a difference?

Comment: I suggest using the types from the Java Collections Framework (in this case `HashMap`, but also `ArrayList` etc.) instead of the pre-JCF classes (`Hashtable`, `Vector`). There API is usually much cleaner, and they all fit well together. The old classes were retrofitted to the new interfaces, which is why their API is not so nice (riddled with duplicate methods, for example). I guess the implementation of the new classes is also better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `this.headers.clone()`, but you need to cast the result. Also this works only in cases where the type is cloneable, and clone does exactly what you want (e.g., in this case a shallow clone).

Aside from that, there is no possibilty, as accessing the runtime type (what you call instance type) of `this.headers` would already involve reflection. However, I would not refrain from using reflection just because someone said its slow. Not all reflective operations are slow (I would for example expect calling `getClass()` on an object to be quite fast.), and not all operations you execute will make a performance difference in your app. This depends on a lot more factors, i.e., how often is this operation executed, how good is the optimizer etc.

The problem with reflection is more that there is no general way to instantiate a specific type. If a class needs constructor arguments, you will need to know which objects to pass to the constructor.

So, think about this: **Do you really need to ensure that is is the exactly same runtime type?** Usually this is not the case. The whole point of programming against interfaces is that you should normally not care about the real runtime type, but only that it implements the correct interface (`Map` here). So the getter in its current form would be fine, even if the runtime type of `this.headers` is actually a `TreeMap` in the future.

However, in this specific case I would suggest a completely different solution. I think it is not good to create a copy of the whole collection on each call to `getResponseHeaders` (I would guess that this is much more expensive than a reflective method call, for example). Instead you can just pass an **unmodifiable view of the collection** to your caller. With this unmodifiable view, the caller will not be able to change your collection, which is usually what you want to ensure. So there is often no need for copying the whole collection.

This can be done very easily by changing the getter method to

```
return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.headers);
```

Note that this way, the callers would see changes of the map, if you change `this.headers` after `getResponseHeaders` was called.

Comment: I'd give +1 even just for the `unmodifiableMap()` mention; I had completely missed that, and it pretty much avoids the entire issue at least in my current situation. Will take `HashMap` for a spin, too.